# Execute a shell script as it would be an interactive session

Tags: bash, shell, output, prompt

For documentation purposes I am trying to execute a shell script in a way that it looks as you typed it by hand in an interactive shell.

Script:

```
x=123
echo $x
```

Then execute:

```
PS4="$PS1"
set -x -v
. ./demo
```

Output:

```
. ./demo
user@host:~/tmp$ . ./demo
x=123
user@host:~/tmp$ x=123
echo $x
user@host:~/tmp$ echo 123
123
```

Desired output:

```
user@host:~/tmp$ x=123
user@host:~/tmp$ echo $x
123
```

It does not have to be bash. Any solution that simulates an interactive session is welcome.

How can I achieve the desired result?

Comment: Did you consider Tcl/Expect?

Comment: @user1934428 I did not even know. Can you provide a solving answer?

Comment: If you google for it (_Tcl/Expect_), you will find plenty of examples on the Web. Try it, and if you get stuck, ask about the concrete point where you can't go on.

Comment: @user1934428 "google for it" is not the purpose of this site. We're collecting useful answers as an encyclopedia for the world after. However, thanks so far! Somebody else might want to take the rep.

Comment: That's correct, but I don't see that it makes sense to repeat here code where you can find plenty of examples on the web. For instance, if you would post here your attempt on doing with _expect_,  and would get stuck at one point, this is something which can be discussed here. But I don't see any attempt from your side to solve it, and in this case, pointing out where to find examples is perfectly inside the purpose of this site.

Comment: @user1934428 As you can see I already did provide an attempt using Bash buitins which did not work as expected. Alternative solutions are really welcome as mentioned in the Q. However, I don't see the point I had to show an attempt for each suggestions from comment. When something can be solved with alternative tools, it is properly placed in an answer. After a while I will come up with some answer myself if nobody else should catch the rep. SO is more like an encylopedia, not just a support system for very specific cases that no one else will ever experience.

Comment: @user1934428 Further more I am trying to form clear and concise questions rather than showing wrong ways which only would make it hard to read as long as it does not contribute to the clarification. I deliberately break down my issues as general as possible to cover a wide range of visitors looking for similar issues. As you can find in my history I spare no effort to contribute to SO in forming good Q/A since I like the idea of SO.

Comment: @user1934428 Creating more questions with specific approaches would just lead to the well known xy-problem. Q wants x, Q thinks y is the solution, A solves y, y ist not the solution for x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pretty simple solution is to start an interactive shell and redirect your script file to the input stream:

```
bash -i </path/to/script-file
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `script`.  It will record your session including timing information and play it back for you.  eg:

```
$ script -r output /bin/sh
Script started, output file is output
sh-3.2$ x=123
sh-3.2$ echo "$x"
123
sh-3.2$ exit
exit

Script done, output file is output
$ script -p output
Script started on Sat Oct 29 20:00:16 2022
sh-3.2$ x=123
sh-3.2$ echo "$x"
123
sh-3.2$ exit
exit

Script done on Sat Oct 29 20:00:22 2022
```

In the above, the first section is entered interactively, and then played back with `script -p`

Comment: Thanks for this interesting alternative I didn't know yet. However, current maintainers package version works different and the input should be done without any errors or it will be replayed as well. The screen shot in documentations should be clean. Thus I prefer to edit the script in an editor first.